# How to expand aliases in fish shell?

Tags: linux, fish

In bash you can expand an alias you type. For example if I have an alias `cmd="cd ~/user"`, typing in `cmd` and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> would change it to `cd ~/user`. Is there a way to do this with fish?

Comment: Have you looked at this bug and subsequent fix: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/393 ? It sounds like what you are looking for, but I'm not familiar enough with fish to be sure; it sounds as though `cmd +` enter will substitute the alias with the definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fish the `alias` command just creates a trivial function. For example,

```
alias cmd 'cd ~/user'
```

Is simply shorthand for

```
function cmd
  cd ~/user
end
```

Because it's a function in fish you can't expand the body in the command line as you type the alias. For your situation I recommend an abbreviation; e.g., `abbr cmd 'cd ~/user'`.